# Store slider value before button click

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro

On `button_click` I have to mute or unmute the sound. It works fine, but I would like to set slider value after unmuting to the value it was before muting and not to a fixed 0.7.

```
private void btnMute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (slider.Value <= 0.0)
    {
        slider.Value = 0.7;
        btnMute.Content = "Mute";
    }

    if (slider.Value > 0.0)
    {
        slider.Value = 0.0;
        btnMute.Content = " UnMute";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Window***

```
  <Grid>
        <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,10,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="250"
            ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
     </Grid>
```

***Code behind:***

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    private double _lastSliderValue;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _lastSliderValue = 0.7;
    }

    private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender,
        RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        // ... Get Slider reference.
        var slider = sender as Slider;
        // ... Get Value.
        if(slider.Value != 0.0)
          _lastSliderValue = slider.Value;
        // ... Set Window Title.
        this.Title = "Value: " + value.ToString("0.0") + "/" + slider.Maximum;
    }

private void btnMute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (slider.Value <= 0.0)
    {
        slider.Value = _lastSliderValue;
        btnMute.Content = "Mute";
    }
    else
    {
        slider.Value = 0.0;
        btnMute.Content = " UnMute";
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `if (slider.Value > 0.0)` should be `else`, otherwise it will never be unmuted.

Comment: Which line you speak about

Comment: @MoezRebai I have accepted your answer, but it wont let me to Vote Up, I need 15+ reputation, sorry.

Comment: ah ok got it Itried to make your reputation but seems to be not possible

Comment: Will try when my reputation will be 15+. You saved my day :)